# irregular Json content

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Right now I'm solving a problem, Ive never run into.
I have an ASP.Net rest API with this class in my models:

```
public class Filter<T> where T : class
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property1", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property2", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Property2 { get; set; } = null;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property3", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
```

However client needs to send me in one of the calls Array like this:

```
    "filter": [
    {
        "property1": "xxxx",
        "property2": "xxxx",
        "property3": "xxxx"
    },
    {
        "property1": "xxxx",
        "property2": ["xxxx","yyyy"],
        "property3": "xxxx"
    }
],
```

Problem is property 2, which is string once and array another time. How can I deal with this type of problem?
Client wont budge. Property is alwayes named as a property2.

Comment: You have to use a more general type like `object`. Then type check it at runtime like `if (filter.Property2 is string value) {}`

Comment: Have you tried using an object type: `public object Property2 { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `JsonConverter` for this. The converter will check if it is an array and if yes return it. If not create one and add the only value as the first object in that array.

```
internal class MyConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken jtoken = JToken.Load(reader);

        if (jtoken.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return jtoken.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<T> { jtoken.ToObject<T>() };
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then change `Property2` to a `List<string>` and add the Converter as a property.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter<string>))]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property2", Required = Required.Always)]
public List<string> Property2 { get; set; }
```

**The test**

```
string json_with_array = "[ { \"property1\": \"xxxx\", \"property2\": \"xxxx\", \"property3\": \"xxxx\" }, { \"property1\": \"xxxx\", \"property2\": [\"xxxx\",\"yyyy\"], \"property3\": \"xxxx\" } ]";
string json_without_array = "[ { \"property1\": \"xxxx\", \"property2\": \"xxxx\", \"property3\": \"xxxx\" }, { \"property1\": \"xxxx\", \"property2\": \"zzzz\", \"property3\": \"xxxx\" } ]";

List<TestClass> list1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestClass>>(json_with_array);
List<TestClass> list2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestClass>>(json_without_array);

List<TestClass> merged_list = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();

string merged_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(merged_list);
```

**The result**

```
[
  {
    "property1": "xxxx",
    "property2": [
      "xxxx"
    ],
    "property3": "xxxx"
  },
  {
    "property1": "xxxx",
    "property2": [
      "xxxx",
      "yyyy"
    ],
    "property3": "xxxx"
  },
  {
    "property1": "xxxx",
    "property2": [
      "xxxx"
    ],
    "property3": "xxxx"
  },
  {
    "property1": "xxxx",
    "property2": [
      "zzzz"
    ],
    "property3": "xxxx"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make some kind of mediator class between your JSON call and Filter class in which you will check for property type instead of instantly mapping it.

Then, change type of your Property2 to array instead of string and check length of your property while using class in order to check if it's a single string or array.

Edit: assuming your array is array of strings. If not, do the same with a general class like object.